# Composition of Analytic Functions

Tags: complex-analysis

I have a basic question in my mind and wish to consult your ideas:

Suppose $\Omega_1$ and $\Omega_2$ are regions, $f$ and $g$
are nonconstant functions defined in $\Omega_1$ and $\Omega_2$, 
respectively, and $f(\Omega_1) \subset \Omega_2$. Define $h=g \circ f$.
What can we say about the third function if

(a) both $g$ and $f$ are analytic;

(b) both $g$ and $h$ are analytic;

(c) both $h$ and $f$ are analytic.

Here I consider all possible cases.

I think in part (a) $h$ is analytic being 
the composition of two differentiable functions.

Actually to my mind, analyticity of $g$ 
implies analyticity of $h$, am I correct ? Otherwise, I can't find counterexamples on each cases.
What is your suggestion?

Thank you.

Comment: Regarding your penultimate paragraph, suppose $g$ is the identity function.

Comment: This has been [crossposted to MO](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/99577/composition-of-analytic-functions)

Comment: This is a great observation!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(a) Function $g \circ f$ is analytic : standard.

(b) Cannot deduce $f$ analytic: $g=17$, $f$ non-analytic.

(c) Cannot deduce $g$ analytic$: f=17$, $g$ non-analytic.